# How to count business days per month for the whole year with different weekmask every week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to make a program that will equally distribute employees' day off. There are 4 groups and each group has it's own `weekmask` for each week of the month. So far I've made a code that will change `weekmask` when it locates 0 in `Dataframe`(Sunday). I'm stuck on structuring this command `np.busday_count(start, end, weekmask=)` to automatically change the start and the end date.

My `Dataframe` looks like this:
[image: Dataframe]

And here's my code:

```
 a: int = 0
 week_mask: str = '1100111' 

 def _change_week_mask():
    global a, week_mask
    a += 1
    if a == 1:
        week_mask = '1111000'
    elif a == 2:
        week_mask = '1111111'
    elif a == 3:
        week_mask = '0011111'
    else:
        a = 0

for line in rows['Workday']:
    if line is '0':
        _change_week_mask()
```

Comment: can you please show the sample output you are expecting?

Comment: @Sach I just want the structure of the command.I've managed so far to change the week's mask and the month.I'm having trouble with the days.
 For example the command should run like that:
The first week of January 2018:
`np.busday_count('2018-01-01', '2018-01-07', weekmask='1100111')`
Second week:
`np.busday_count('2018-01-08', '2018-01-14', weekmask='1111000')`
etc.
Although the first week of December 2018:
`np.busday_count('2018-12-01', '2018-12-02', weekmask='1100111')`
Second week:
`np.busday_count('2018-12-03', '2018-12-09', weekmask='1111000')`
etc.

Comment: @Sach In my `Dataframe` you can notice, that I solve this problem with zeros in `Workday` column. I want the first day of the dataframe until first zero to be placed automatically in the command. Then the next value from the first zero to the next zero and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: changed the value of start week from 6 to 0.

Ok, so to answer your problem I have created the sample data frame with below code.

Then I have added below columns to the data frame.

- dayofweek - to reach to similar data which you created by setting every Sunday as zero. In this case Monday is set as zero and Sunday is six.
- weeknum - week of year
- week -  instead of counting and than changing the week mask, I have assigned the value to week from 0 to 3 and based on it, we can calculate the mask.
- weekmask - using value of the week, I have calculate the mask, you might need to align this as per your logic.
- weekenddate- end date I have calculate by adding 7 to start date, if month is changing mid week then this will have month end date.

b

after this we can create a new data frame to have only end of week entry, in this case Monday is 0 so I have taken 0.

then you can apply function and store the result to data frame.
import datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'startdate':pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-01'), pd.to_datetime('2018-11-30'))})
df_['dayofweek'] = df_.startdate.dt.dayofweek
df_['remaining_days_in_month'] = df_.startdate.dt.days_in_month - df_.startdate.dt.day
df_['week'] = df_.startdate.dt.week%4
df_['day'] = df_.startdate.dt.day
df_['weekmask'] = df_.week.map({0 : '1100111', 1 : '1111000' , 2 :  '1111111', 3: '0011111'})
df_['weekenddate'] = [x[0] +  datetime.timedelta(days=(7-x[1])) if x[2] > 7-x[1] else x[0] +  datetime.timedelta(days=(x[2])) for x in df_[['startdate','dayofweek','remaining_days_in_month']].values]
final_df = df_[(df_['dayofweek']==0) | ( df_['day']==1)][['startdate','weekenddate','weekmask']]

final_df['numberofdays'] = [ np.busday_count((x[0]).astype('<M8[D]'), x[1].astype('<M8[D]'), weekmask=x[2]) for x in final_df.values.astype(str)]
```

Output:

```
  startdate weekenddate weekmask numberofdays
0 2018-10-01 2018-10-08 1100111 5 
7 2018-10-08 2018-10-15 1111000 4
14 2018-10-15 2018-10-22 1111111 7
21 2018-10-22 2018-10-29 0011111 5
28 2018-10-29 2018-10-31 1100111 2
31 2018-11-01 2018-11-05 1100111 3
35 2018-11-05 2018-11-12 1111000 4
42 2018-11-12 2018-11-19 1111111 7
49 2018-11-19 2018-11-26 0011111 5
56 2018-11-26 2018-11-30 1100111 2
```

let me know if this needs some changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Well done, though it's a completely different approach to what I want to achieve. I want to calculate automatically everything for each year. So if we run the program in 2030 it will still be working. I made everything, the only problem which remains is the command. I've tried to make an iterator instead of a list with all the Sundays of the year, still nothing.